# Wordpress - How to link thumbnail to a link assigned in admin

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get my thumbnail to link to a link I've assigned in admin when uploading the feature image. So far the thumbnail doesn't appear to have a link at all. This is the code that I have.

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 9)); ?> 

<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>

     <div class="leftimage">   <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?></div>
     <div class="textright"><h4><b><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></b></h4>
        <?php echo $page->post_content; ?> <p></p>

        </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated! I just don't know how to get the thumbnail to link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom field called `your_link_url` when editing your posts. In your loop, you can then create a link using that custom field to wrap your featured image.  See below:

```
<?php $pages = get_pages(array('child_of' => 9)); ?> 
<?php foreach ($pages as $page): ?>

     <div class="leftimage">
        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_link_url', true) ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
        </a>
     </div>
     <div class="textright">
         <h4><strong><?php echo $page->post_title; ?></strong></h4>
         <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>
     </div>
```

I also replaced your `<b>` tag with `<strong>` and removed an empty `<p>` tag.